# PostgreSQL and sorting, set locale at Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

I recently pushed my first Ruby on Rails app to Heroku and I have an issue with the sorting. I have swedish characters such as Å Ä and Ö which are not properly sorted. They are sorted as A A and O. I think this has to do with the locale setting of the postgresql database, correct?

Is it possible to change the locale to Swedish when I'm using a shared database on Heroku? If so, how do I do that?

If *not*, can I somehow order it correctly using some RoR-magic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to be on 'the cutting edge' you could use the new Heroku labs plugin https://github.com/heroku/heroku-labs which will let you enable Postgres 9.1 (as opposed to the default 8.3 Postgres) for your application and then use the 9.1 collation support.

As always, it's labs so that means it comes with risks but I'm yet to see heroku release to public beta and then yank it later.

Comment: Thank you! Will have a look at that! :)

Comment: I just got a reply from heroku when asking about this plugin: http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/labs-heroku-shared-postgresql which is what you mean I guess? In the response I got they wrote: `"One of our data engineers just informed me that the following locales are supported:

C 
en_US 
en_US.utf8 
POSIX

So no Swedish yet, but we're looking into it."`